# How to use redis as partial LRU?

Tags: redis

I have 2 types of redis keys: `post:{pid}` and `comment:{cid}`.

I would like to store cache of either type at most 100 records.

e.g. I have 100 post records and 50 comment ones. When a comment record comes, it will be saved. When a post record comes, one existing record will be replaced.

Comment: If you number the keys sequentially then when you add {x} you can delete {x-100}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis' caching capabilities do not do that. You'll need to track and remove the keys yourself. A Sorted Set, where the member is a key's name and the score is a timestamp, can be used for that purpose.

Note: LRU mean Least-Recently-Used, whereas what you're describing is eviction based on order of creation. Nuance.